# Build Class object from txt file line

Tags: c++

I have the following code and I want to build an object. How could I do it? Any ideas? The class is of type {sting,int,int}.

code:

```
void StudentRepository::loadStudents(){
    ifstream fl;
    fl.open("studs.txt");
    Student A();
    if(fl.is_open()){
        while(!(fl.eof())){
            getline(???); //i dont knwo houw coudl i limit what i want were...

        }
    }
    else{
        cout<<"~~~ File couldn't be open! ~~~"<<endl;
    }
}
```

Save to file funcntion:

```
void StudentRepository::saveStudents(){
    ofstream fl;
    fl.open("studs.txt");
    if(fl.is_open()){
        for(unsigned i=0; i<students.size(); i++){
            fl<<students[i].getName();
            fl<<",";
            fl<<students[i].getID();
            fl<<",";
            fl<<students[i].getGroup();
            fl<<","<<endl;
        }
    }
    else{
    cout<<"~~~ File couldn't be open! ~~~"<<endl;
}
```

I tried to implement some limits but that is not working... How canI do this?

Initially I just wrote the object to file but it is harder to get them back to the object....
File content:

```
maier ewew 123 232
tudor efsw 13 2323
```

Comment: would you be so kind as to show us what `studs.txt` contains?

Comment: the file is an rewritable file. i do save my work on.

Comment: What do you mean by _limit_? [`std::getline()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) will read up to the newline character (and discard it). Don't use `while (!fl.eof()) {}`, check immediately `if (getline(...))` was successful.

Comment: ok but i want to crate an object of 3 elemetns 1 string 2 ints... can getline() do that?

Comment: Yes, it will read a full line (which appears to be comma separated). You then need to split the line into its three parts.

Comment: Use `std::string::find()` and `std::string::substr()`.  [`std::string` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would overloading the input and output operators for the Student type work for you?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

class Student {
public:
    Student() : name(""),id(0),group(0) {}
    Student(const string &_name, const int &_id, const int &_group) : name(_name), id(_id), group(_group) {}

    friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &out, const Student &stud);
    friend istream &operator>>(istream &in, Student &stud);
private:
    string name;
    int id;
    int group;
};    

ostream &operator<<(ostream &out, const Student &stud) {
    out << stud.name << " " << stud.id << " " << stud.group << endl;
    return out;
}

istream &operator>>(istream &in, Student &stud) {
    string name, surname;
    in >> name >> surname >> stud.id >> stud.group;
    stud.name = name + " " + surname;
    return in;
}    

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    Student john("john doe", 214, 43);
    Student sally("sally parker", 215, 42);
    Student jack("jack ripper", 114, 41);

    ofstream out("studentfile.txt");
    out << john;
    out << sally;
    out << jack;
    out.close();

    Student newstud;
    ifstream in("studentfile.txt");
    in >> newstud;
    cout << "Read " << newstud;
    in >> newstud;
    cout << "Read " << newstud;
    in >> newstud;
    cout << "Read " << newstud;
    in.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Adding some standard checks for I/O to check that whatever you are reading is valid should do it.